# Работа с файлами на Android

Tags: eclipse, android, java

Как осуществить проверку существует ли файл или нет? Если существует, то произвести его чтение, иначе же создать, и произвести запись...

Пытался создать файл таким образом:

```
File myF = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(),"file.txt");
try
{
    myF.createNewFile();
    text.setText(myF.getAbsolutePath());
}
catch (IOException e1) 
{
    text.setText(e1.toString()); 
}
```

В итоге пишет `java.io.IOException: Permission denied`

Да и в любом случае при применение метода `createNewFile()` вылезает это...

После долгих блужданий по инету я нашел решение своей проблемы...

изначально в manifest-файл приложения нужно было добавить следующую строку

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Далее все происходит так:

```
File myF = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/data/", "file.txt");
if (!myF.exists())
{
    try
    {
        String str = "0";
        myF.createNewFile();
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(myF.getAbsolutePath(), 0);
        OutputStreamWriter outStr = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            outStr.write(str);
            outStr.flush();
            outStr.close();
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e1)
    {
       text.setText(e1.toString());
    }
}
else
{
     text.setText("Файл есть!");
}
```

Но теперь вылезает:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File mnt//sdcard//data//file.txt contains a path separator

Полазив нашел что "`openFileOutput` не может принимать путь, а только имя файла.."

Но как тогда обратится к созданному файлу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге нашелся такой выход:

```
File myF = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/data/","file.txt");
    if(!myF.exists())
    {

        try
        {
            String str = "500";
            myF.createNewFile();
            try 
            {
                FileWriter fWr = new FileWriter(myF);                   
                fWr.write(str);
                fWr.flush();
                fWr.close();      
            }
            catch (Throwable t) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            text.setText("Бюджет - "+str+" р.");
        }
        catch (Exception e1) 
        {
           text.setText(e1.toString()); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try {
                FileReader fRd = new FileReader(myF);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fRd);
                String str;
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    buffer.append(str + "\n");
                }                        
                fRd.close();
                text.setText("Бюджет - "+buffer.toString()+"р.");
            }
        catch (Throwable t) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exception: " + t.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Всем спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Кстати, если у вас при записи произойдет исключение, то поток не закроется вообще. Это неверно.

Answer (score 4):

```
File file = new File(path);
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile()
    // и писать
    FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(file.getAbsolutePath(), MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    osw.write("сюда писать инфу");
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
} else {
    // читать
    FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput(file.getAbsolutePath());
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
    char[] inputBuffer = new char[bufSize];
    isr.read(inputBuffer);
    String read = new String(inputBuffer);
}
```

Флаг MODE_WORLD_READABLE позволяет другим приложениям получить доступ к файлу с правами чтения. Есть еще MODE_PRIVATE - только создатель получает доступ, и MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE - все приложения могут писать в этот файл. Флаги определены в классе Context.

[Как читать и писать в файл](http://www.anddev.org/working_with_files-t115.html)

Comment: Спасибо! А где будет создан файл, если указать так

    File file = new File(path);
    file.createNewFile();

а то я не могу найти его на сматрфоне...

Comment: /data/data/package/files/file.txt как мне думается

Comment: у меня нету вообще такого пути, только папка /data

Файл вообще не создается... Не пишет и не читает.. ничего не делает...

Comment: у вас скорее всего нет прав писать этот файл. Смотрите логи.

Comment: Где смотреть? Что смотреть? Как смотреть?..

Comment: adb logcat

Comment: это что? эт где? в эклипс или в смартфоне?...

Comment: в эклипс это DDMS. Гугл в помощь.