# Как записать объект в файл

Tags: android, serializable

Есть следующий класс, меня интересуют каким  способом можно сохранить этот объект в  файл. Нужно хранить список таких объектов.

Я использую следующий код:

```
public class Serialization {
    Context context;

    public Serialization(MainActivity activity) {
        context = activity;
    }

    public void serialization(Contact contact) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = context.openFileOutput("/contact.ser",Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(contact);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
        System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in /contact.ser");
    }

    public void deserialization(){

        Contact e;
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fileIn = context.openFileInput("/contact.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            e = (Contact) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        }catch(IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
        {
            System.out.println("Contact class not found");
            c.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Deserialized Employee...");
        System.out.println("Name: " + e.getDisplayName());
        System.out.println("ID: " + e.getId());
        System.out.println("Phone: " + e.getPhone().get(0));
    }
}
```

И получаю ошибку:                                                                       `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /contact.ser contains a path separator`

Я так понимаю,ошибка в указании пути, в чем может быть проблема?

```
public class Contact implements Serializable{
    private String id;
    private String displayName;
    private ArrayList<Phone> phone;
    private ArrayList<Email> email;
    private ArrayList<Note> notes;
    private ArrayList<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
    private ArrayList<IM> imAddresses;
    private Organization organization;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/40851/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File /contact.ser contains a path separator, дословно.

> Файл /contact.ser содержит разделитель пути.

Ответ на вопрос:

```
   File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "appSaveState.data");
   out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile));
```

Comment: А куда оно в таком случае сохранит файл?  можно ли каким то образом указать папку в которую я хочу сохранять, к примеру, где то в папке проекта сохранять?